# How do I save a selection programmatically?

Tags: jsx, adobe-illustrator, extendscript

In Adobe Illustrator I can select something on the Artboard and then go to Selection > Save Selection and give it a name. That stored selection is also stored in the .ai file and can be selected when reopening the file.

Is the same possible with using ExtendScript?

So far I only found a way to select everything with `app.activeDocument.selectObjectsOnActiveArtboard()`, then either cut/copy the selection with `app.copy()` or `app.cut()` and paste it into another document with `app.paste()`. But I haven't found the option to save the selection in the document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you can run almost any menu command from a script.

The script to save the current selection look like this:

```
app.executeMenuCommand('Selection Hat 10');
```

But there will be the dialog window to input a name for this selection.

[image]

I'm not sure if it's possible to avoid the dialog window and assign the name via a script.

Comment: This helps me a LOT. This function is not documented.
With setting `app.userInteractionLevel = UserInteractionLevel.DONTDISPLAYALERTS;` in the script, the dialog is not opened at all. The selection is then saved with the default name as `Selection 1` and increments the number at the end with each execute.
I will try to find out, if I can somehow set the dialogs input value.

Comment: Yep, Illustrator's JS engine is extremely poor documented. I've took the fancy command 'Selection Hat 10'  from here: https://github.com/ten-A/AiMenuObject

Comment: But will it save to another document?

Comment: No, I think it won't save anything to another document. It's just one line to demonstrate how you can run one of the menu items from your script. If you want to perform more complicated task you probably need a proper script with many other lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround you can save IDs of selected page items in the text file (in the same folder as the document) with a script like this:

```
// put IDs of all selected items into the array
var sel = app.selection;
var ids = [];
while (sel.length) ids.push(sel.shift().uuid);

// save the array in the file 'selection.txt'
var file = File(app.activeDocument.path + '/selection.txt');
file.open('w');
file.write(ids.toSource());
file.close();
```

And then you can load the IDs from the file and select all page items by their IDs with the second script as follows:

```
// deselect all just in case
app.selection = null;

// load IDs from the file 'selection.txt'
var doc = app.activeDocument;
var file = File(doc.path + '/selection.txt');
var ids = $.evalFile(file);

// loop through all page items and select items that have the ID from the file
var pageItems = doc.pageItems;
for (var j = 0; j < pageItems.length; j++) {
    for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
        if (pageItems[j].uuid == ids[i]) {
            pageItems[j].selected = true;
            ids.splice(i,1); // remove founded id from the array
        }
    }
}
```